# C# Visual Studio Intellisense autocomplete inserts redundant newline

Tags: c#, visual-studio, intellisense

This is best explained by a gif of what's going on:

[image: VSAutoComplete]

I can try to describe it as well. I start typing `stri` and tab autocomplete to `string`. Add a property name (just `Name` in this case) and then when I type space the intellisense autocomplete suggests the auto `get; set;` as I want. When I tab to insert it, the braces are weirdly split between two lines, in a way I can't imagine anyone would want.

So I end up with this:

```
string Name
{
get; set; }
```

Any idea what's going on? I was trying to change the settings in editorconfig for expression bodied methods (I don't want those when implementing interfaces, as the first thing I usually do is to add code to methods). But this is just madness. I'm trying to delete all .editorconfig files and .vs folders, but so far I'm not getting rid of this crap.

Comment: Ok, some combination of deleting .editorconfig and .vs folders all over my harddrive seems to have fixed this....